# Bash echo and actions order

Tags: bash, echo

I have created a bash script to find files matching a pattern, and copying them if found.
My idea is basically:

- Echo "starting"
- listing files here
- Echo "found one"
- copying it
- on to the next to test it
- Echo "done"

But basically what I get is the script doing its job, and echoing one "found one" in the end for each relevant file, as if my script was processing all requests and then echoing, rather than following that order I tried to have. What am I doing wrong ? thanks !

Comment: "rather than following that order I tried to have" - have what?

Comment: I smell Microsoft with this strategy :-). You need a rethink your approach to this kind of tasks. Building enormous lists then walk over them is a signal to bad code design (I don't say it is always avoidable, though).

Answer (score 2):

Based on these very small amount of information your problem could be a whole range from "syntax error" to "ultimately not understanding how shell scripts work".
However as this is an 'answer' I try to answer you question. If the projected task is only "find files matching a pattern, and copying them if found" then there is already a command that does this:

```
$ find ./ -name "m*a*tch" -exec cp {} <destination> \;
```

'find' finds files based on a pattern, then it can do a gazillion thing, one example is to run bash commands.
The string after "-exec" can be any shell command (more than one) or even a call to an existing shell script. The line must be closed with that "\;". The "{}" represents the filename that is found by the pattern, where filename means the whole path to the file.

A general idea: if you need to do something in linux, there is a fat chance that a command already does it, so begin with reading documentation and you can save a lot of work while gathering knowledge.